# Maven download dependencies while ignoring failures

Tags: java, docker, maven, docker-compose

I'm containerizing some ancient app, with a bunch of dependencies that work fine when building, but make dependency:go-offline and dependency:resolve go crazy. Since I can't use build kit or volumes during build time, I still need to somehow make sure I'm not downloading every dependency each build.

The thing is, the ones that are failing aren't necessary. They get created during the install. I don't need them, let them fail.

I've gone so far as to create a fake jar file with "touch" but clearly there has to be a better way.

1. Fixing these dependencies so they resolve on their own would take forever and yield very little reward
2. I can't really create new profiles because these pom.xml are massive and there's like 9 of them. It's not feasible.

I've been trying with

```
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline dependency:resolve-plugins -DexcludeGroupIds -DexcludeTransitive=true -DexcludeGroupIds=com.problematic.group -f path-to-pom
```

And got nowhere. It doesn't seem that these arguments work how I imagine them to work. I just don't want this plugin to resolve them. They're there, just don't worry about it and stop failing.

What *kinda* works (but it's an awful solution) is that I just ignore the failure on a docker level.

I don't think I really need to share code here, and all these inter-connected pom.xml because you either know exactly what I'm talking about or you don't.

Overall I feel like there has to be a better solution in 2023 with these kind of apps getting on docker.  I already have like 59 layers, I'm going insane.

Comment: Have you tried to mark the dependencies with runtime scope?

Comment: Alternatively to runtime you can try the optional dependency
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: If you like ` I still need to somehow make sure I'm not downloading every dependency each build.`  you need to make your cache non volatile.. either provide it as a volume during the build in your continainer or build your app locally on your CI before you build the container... and only copy the final app into your container or layered container with different deps. Apart from that: `dependency:go-offline dependency:resolve-plugins` if you go-offline no resolution will work which has not been resolved already ... this looks completely wrong..

Comment: Provide it during build time? If that was possible that would be very easy, but I specified that I don't have access to this. I'm using podman, 3.4.4 and that does not have build time volumes. Building it somewhere else defeats the purpose completely.

Comment: @aled how would I do that? All resources take me to changing pom.xml, so I'm not quite sure where I'd find the right flag to set.

Comment: Add to the question examples of the dependencies in the pom.